# Windows Batch - default choice with timeout

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

In a cmd window, I want to prompt the user for a set of choices (denoted by letters), one being the default. 
The user can key in a letter or hit `Enter`, in which case the default choice will be selected.

I also want to specify a timeout, so the default choice is auto-selected after a given number of seconds of inactivity.

The built-in `choice` command comes close:

```
> choice /C YN /T 5 /D Y /M "The message"
```

This takes only valid choices ( `/C YN`) and auto-defaults to 'Y' (`/D Y`) after 5 seconds (`/T 5`)
... but it strangely does not allow hitting `Enter` for the default choice.

The other, more verbose option I found permits hitting 'Enter' for the default choice:

```
:ch
set sel=Y

REM Hitting Enter does not modify 'sel'
set /p sel=The message, [Y/N]?

if %sel% == Y goto Yes
if %sel% == N goto No

echo Invalid choice '%sel%', try again.
goto ch
```

...but I don't know how to make this one auto-select the default after a while.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an option, unless you find some 3rd CLI app that can do it.

How about VBS? it'll be way easier to do that...

Comment: I'm not opposed to throwing a vbs script in the %PATH% and using it like a built-in command. But I don't know vbs.